# Spring Reactor: switchIfEmpty with onErrorContinue - Bug or Feature?

Tags: java, kotlin, project-reactor

I have made a interesting observation using **switchIfEmpty** in conjunction with **onErrorContinue**.

Given the following pipeline (in Kotlin):

```
Flux.fromIterable(keys).concatMap { key ->
     someRepository.findByKey(key)
        .map { domain -> someFunction(domain) }
        .flatMap { domain -> someRepository.save(domain) }
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer { onEmptyFunction().toMono() })
    }
```

The outer pipeline maps a Flux of keys to a Mono of a domain object and pipes it through the `someFunction` and saves it through the `someRepository` function.

If the `findByKey` function completes without data (cannot find the domain object in the repo) it should straight go to the `switchIfEmpty` in the pipline. Okay so far so good.

The above description works perfectly until the inner pipeline throws an Exception. Then the pipeline does not continue any further and the subscriber will get notified by its onError consumer function.

What if we want to continue the inner pipeline even if an Exception is thrown and just try the next key from the outer Flux?

Thats possible and we introduce a new operator **onErrorContinue**:

```
Flux.fromIterable(keys).concatMap { key ->
     someRepository.findByKey(key)
        .map { domain -> someFunction(domain) }
        .flatMap { domain -> someRepository.save(domain) }
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer { onEmptyFunction().toMono() })
    }.onErrorContinue(::someLog)
```

Now the pipeline should continue working even if the inner pipeline throws an exception (and it does so, I tested it).

**However, here comes the interesting observation:**
The switchIfEmpty function is **ALSO** getting called if the inner pipeline throws an Exception.

This means `switchIfEmpty` gets executed in **TWO** events:
- findByKey completes with an empty Mono
- inner pipeline throws an Exception (e.g. `someFunction`)

This is fundamentally different from above pipeline without `onErrorContinue` where the switchIfEmpty is **NOT** executed if the inner pipeline throws an Exception.

**Questions:**
Is this intended behaviour?
Is this a bug?
Can i somehow control that switchIfEmtpy is **ONLY** executed on `empty data` not on `errors`?

This is is really a dangerous situation which bugged me for a while!

Comment: onErrorContinue is a quite special operator, I recommend reading this discussion: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/210 Although, I'm not entirely sure if this is the intended behavior here.

Comment: Thanks. That Link helped a bit to clear the mud!

Comment: I have a similar problem and created [an issue on github](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2602), because that behavior is really strange.